# dotnet core portable angular app not running

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core

I've downloaded Node v12.8.1 binaries aswell as Dotnet core 3.0.100 Binaries. I set the environment variables for windows manually (for this user, as i do not have admin rights). I managed to get a isolated angular app running, a isolated node.js helloworld.js and a dotnet core mini api.

All of that worked so far. Now i tried to create a dotnet core angular app using `dotnet new angular` and it created a couple of boilerplate including a "ClientApp" folder which includes the angular client application.

Without changing anything i simply tried to run `dotnet run` and i got an error stating that "node --version" was terminated with exit code 1 and

> error : Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE.

Now what i was thinking is that somehow dotnet core tries to find node js using System environment path instead of user environment path. I am not sure about this however.

Does anyone know how i can solve or bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to remove the Node.js version check in the `.csproj` of your project. I mean this part:

```
<!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
<Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
</Exec>
<Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
```